# Only one submit form generating You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403

Pulling my hairs out on this one..
Suddenly the form I'm working on generates Forbidden error..

```
You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Normally this is a rights issue, I know... But not in this case..
I restored an earlier backup of the form and this one works!

NOT WORKING:
http://www.plastischechirurgie.nu/theme-options/index.html

WORKING
http://www.plastischechirurgie.nu/theme-options001/index.html

I compared both forms but can't find a clue why one works and the other not!

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance
Quokka

Comment: What form are we talking about? I only see a search box and both boxes work.

Answer (score 0):

Think it's mod_security not liking some or one field in the new form.. I'll post this question in mod_security section!